# How to halt rendering of dynamic search results in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working on creating a dynamic search results workflow. I can make the results render with no issue, but can't figure out how best to toggle them off when I delete all the input from the search bar. If you start typing, addresses appear that match, but then as you delete all the way they don't all go away.

My thoughts were to use one of the two parameters in my state variables: `showMatches` or `matches.length`. I am struggling to see the final piece to this puzzle. Below is my current code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Match from './Match';
//import Render from './Render';

const my_data = require('./data/test.json')

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    links: [],
    selectedLink:null,
    userLocation: {},
    searchInput: "",
    showMatches: false,
    matches: [],
    searchLink:[]
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/s4kf-3yrf.json')
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(res=> 
            //console.log(json)
            this.setState({links:res})
        );
}

handleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({searchInput: event.target.value })
    this.updateMatches()  
    console.log(this.state.showMatches)
    console.log(this.state.matches.length)
  }

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.displayMatches();
}

findMatches = (wordToMatch, my_obj) => {
    return my_obj.filter(place => {
        // here we need to figure out the matches
        const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        //console.log(place.street_address.match(regex))
        return place.street_address.match(regex)
    });
}

updateMatches =() => {
    const matchArray = this.findMatches(this.state.searchInput, this.state.links);
    const newStateMatches = matchArray.map(place => {
      //console.log(place.street_address);
      return place 
    });
    this.setState({matches:newStateMatches})
    this.state.matches.length > 1 ? this.setState({showMatches: true}) : this.setState({showMatches: false})  
  }

alertClicked = address => {
    //event.preventDefault(); // not sure what event you're preventing
    this.setState({searchLink: address});
    this.pushData();
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input 
                placeholder="Search for a Link Near you..." 
                onChange = {this.handleInputChange} 
                value = {this.state.searchInput}
            />
            <ListGroup defaultActiveKey="#link1">
              {
                this.state.matches.map(match => {
                  return <Match 
                            address={match.street_address} 
                            alertClicked={this.alertClicked}
                            value = {this.state.searchLink}
                            logState={this.logState}/>
                })
              }
            </ListGroup>


        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

**Match.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

const match = ({ alertClicked, address }) => {

return (
    <ListGroup.Item 
        className="Matches"
        action 
        // function expressions could cause this to rerender unnecessarily.
        onClick={(address) => alertClicked(address)}> 
          <p>{`${address}`}</p>
    </ListGroup.Item>
)
}



export default match;
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Your matches logic needs to check if `this.state.searchInput` is an empty string and return an empty array in that case. (also, `setState` is asynchronous; your code doesn't properly deal with that fact; to run a function after the state was changed, you can pass it as 2nd argument to `setState()`)

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for the tip on this. I'm starting to learn that I need to take into account the asynchronous nature of things in javascript and react, it sometimes still eludes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I think you could implement this is in your `handleInputChange`, like so :

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  if (event.target.value.length === 0) {
   this.setState({searchInput: "", showMatches: false, matches: [] })
   return
  }
  this.setState({searchInput: event.target.value })
  this.updateMatches()  
}
```

But what do you mean by "but then as you delete all the way they don't all go away" ? Sounds like there actually might be a bug in you `updateMatches`.

EDIT: Chris' comment is spot on regarding `updateMatches`.

Comment: You should still look into what the comment mentioned regarding your matching logic! This is a bare minimum solution that relies on a hard reset of your state, probably not a *true* solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading up on it right now, definitely don't want to be relying on bad practices. Thanks for the heads up.